# Django How to Exclude GET Parameters When Comparing Current Page to request.get_full_path

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have my templates set up in a way similar to this:

```
{% url 'index' as index %}

<div>
    {% if request.get_full_path == index %}
        This is the index
    {% else %}
        This is not the index
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Here is the issue: If my page has a get request attached to the url, then the comparison automatically fails. So, even if I am on `/index/?q=search-results`, the `request.get_full_path == index` comparison fails. Is there a solution to strip get queries from the comparison?

Comment: Have you tried to use just `request.path`?

Comment: Rahul just suggested it, so I did and it worked perfectly - thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 3):

You can **use [`request.path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path)** instead to compare the path of the requested page with the `index` url. This will not include the query string if there was any.

> A string **representing the full path to the requested page**, not
>   including the scheme or domain.

[`request.get_full_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path) returns the `path` along with the query string.

> Returns the `path`, **plus an appended query string**, if applicable.

```
{% url 'index' as index %}

<div>
    {% if request.path == index %} # use request.path instead
        This is the index
    {% else %}
        This is not the index
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Quickest correct answer I've ever gotten on such a simple oversight :P
I will award the correct answer to you as soon as the cooldown timer is up... thanks!

Comment: Another question btw - what if the index was personalized such that it looks like `/index/USERNAME/`? Is there a way to compare the base url **without** a kwarg?

Comment: I don't think you can directly do that using `url` tag without the necessary `username` kwargs because without that kwarg, there would be no mapped url and you will get a `NoReverseMatch` exception. You can instead do  `{% if request.path == /index/ %}` i.e. use the index value which you want to compare.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if request.path == request.get_full_path %}
```

`request.path` will give you the relative path without your GET parameters